# Ajax and java servlet data transfer using java script

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

Hello guys I am new to ajax, trying to create a simple basic data transfer between servlet and html page using javascript(don't know jQuery). But that's not working tried reading tutorials but still can't figure out the problem. Can someone tell me where i am doing it wrong.

Html page
index.html

```
<body>
    <button onClick="run()">Click</button>
    <script>
        function run() {
            if(window.XMLHttpResquest) xmlhttp=new XMLHttpResquest();
            else  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            xmlhttp.open("GET","/test",false);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <br>
    <p id="demo">Static</p>
</body>
```

Servlet : Test.java

```
package foo;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException {
        res.setContentType("text/plain");
        res.getWriter().write("Dynamic");
    }
}
```

WebServer i am using is tomcat, web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>tst</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>foo.Test</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>tst</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Edit:

What problem I am facing is - when I click on the 'click button' the innerHTML of the paragraph element should change but it is not changing. I tried runnig the servlet from address bar to check for servlet errors it's working it prints "Dynamic " so not a problem with the servlet and Web.xml file.

Comment: what is not working,are you getting any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write 'xmlhttp.send(null)' after 'onreadystatechange' function. Hopefully it should work. 
Moreover, you don't need to pass 'null' in send.

Following code works for me perfectly file. Another change I made is to add '.' period in URL before '/' in open(). And I called the send() after declaring the function for onreadystatechange.

```
<body>
    <button onClick="run()">Click</button>
     <script>
        function run() {
            if(window.XMLHttpResquest) xmlhttp=new XMLHttpResquest();
            else  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            xmlhttp.open("GET","./test",false);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
    <br>
    <p id="demo">Static</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Moved the line below the function still not working.

Comment: I've also modified the url.. check "xmlhttp.open("GET","./test",false);"

Comment: :) pretty strange.. the code which I pasted works fine, for sure.. 
have you used firebug or IE developer tools to track the network traffic and JS debug?
That will be helpful.

Comment: It's true in xmlhttp.open for asynchronous it worked. Change it to true in your answer.